# vue-i18n: Is there a way to set a locale manually inside $t method?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am working on a project using Firestore and vue-18n. What I want to is to save a translated message into Firestore and I want to set a locale manually inside `$t` method. My code is like this.

```
methods: {
    doSomething() {
        ...
        db.collection('messages').add({
            body: this.$t('componentName.hello'), // I want to set a locale here
        })
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set a locale inside `$t` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
 body: this.$t('componentName.hello', locale), //for example "en"
...
```

source: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/blob/5.x/gitbook/api.md#tkeypath-lang-arguments